# Где изучить Gradle?

Tags: android, gradle

знаю, что такое непринято спрашивать, но я без понятия где еще узнать, так что извиняюсь заранее.
хочу больше узнать про Gradle в контексте Android-разработки.
как он работает? как собирает проекты? как я могу оптимизировать сборку?
даже банально как под копотом работают implementation и testImplementation ?
можете подсказать, где это можно почитать или какие-то курсы по этой теме?

Comment: книга есть в сети Gradle Recipes for Android: Master the New Build System for Android

Answer (score 1):

Как минимум - [официальная документация по Gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide.html).

Также можно обратиться [сюда](https://coderlessons.com/tutorials/raznoe/vyuchit-gradle/uchebnik-gradle)

Ну и на крайний случай, если вдруг стоит задача узнать что-то конкретное - [сюда](https://habr.com/ru/search/?q=gradle)

Думаю, что для знания основных аспектов достаточно будет лишь документации.